# Find angle EFD, giving reasons

Tags: geometry

[image]

I've stared at this for a good 15mins, and can't figure out were to start. I see alternate angles, but they only apply to parallel lines.

I tried 180 - 22 - 58 = 100, is that correct?

Comment: What you tried would be wrong, as they are not parallel. Look at the triangle ADC. Can you find <D there?

Answer (score 1):

When you stare, look only for the figures that you are familiar with.[image]

Answer (score 0):

First solve for triangle $∠ADC$:
$∠ADC= 180^\circ - (22^\circ + 37^\circ)
      =180^\circ - 59^\circ
      =121^\circ $(angle sum of triangle)

Now solve for $∠D$:
$∠D= 180^\circ - 121^\circ
    =59^\circ $(exterior angle of triangle)

I'm unsure how to reason this question but I know this has to be the answer.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Your work is fine so far, but you're missing one last step. If you have $\angle FED$ and $\angle FDE$, what's the missing angle?

Answer (score 0):

Facts:

A-The sum of angles on one side of a straight line=$180$ degrees.

B-The sum of angles inside a triangle = $180$ degrees.

Solution:

1-Find angle:FDC (using A).

2-Find angle:FDE (using A)

3-Find angle: EFD (using B).

[image]